# How long does it take for a bounty to be autoaccepted?

Tags: support, bounties

```
This question had a bounty worth +250 reputation from XXX that ended 10 mins ago.
```

Is there a delay between the end of the bounty and the bounty being autoaccepted and awarded? I didn't read the FAQ description as indicating anything like this...

Comment: Normally, there's a scant few minutes that pass before it occurs, so some delay is expected. I'm more surprised that the syntax changed from "has" to "had". Can you link this example that you've just seen?

Comment: If no answers met the criteria (posted after the bounty was started and have a score of at least +2) then the bounty won't be awarded.

Comment: In addition to what Grace said, I think I remember reading that the bounty script runs approximately every hour. A link to the post in question would definitely be useful (or, at least, would have been, since it's now been 17 hours).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) (I was too lazy to check what the FAQ said at the time this question was asked, but it's certainly a duplicate now.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In June 2011 [things changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remaining/74037#74037), and it now takes at least 24 hours<sup>†</sup>, during which the bounty can still be awarded manually. (To answers that were eligible when the bounty expired.)

<sup><sup>†</sup> Actually, it's [even 25 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104919/bounty-auto-awarded-after-6-days/104941#104941) on regular days when daylight saving time doesn't start or end. So, it could even be 26 hours!</sup>

Comment: waffles ran some stats and it turns out that 24 hour grace period really DID help people accept more answers, the data supports it. So the community was right about the need for a grace period, and I was wrong to resist it.