# Bounty auto-awarded after 6 days

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

I set a bounty on [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/150/pourquoi-trente-six) (on [French L&U](https://french.stackexchange.com/)). According to both the [recorded history](https://french.stackexchange.com/posts/150/revisions) and my memory, the bounty was set on 2011-08-27 14:09:30Z and awarded (for half the amount) on 2011-09-02 13:57:43Z. That means it lasted 6 days minus a few minutes.

I think I remember getting the 3-day warning, though I couldn't tell if I got it at the right time. Furthermore, the author of the question [reports](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1836740#1836740) that he received a top bar notification about the auto-awarding. I didn't receive the customary email reminder.

[image: history screenshot]

Comment: We just had a flag like this on SO.  I'm not up to date on how bounties work, so I didn't know if this was expected behavior or not.

Comment: @genesis-φ [9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97243/bounty-ends-are-too-in#comment-244732), [11](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98662/please-clear-flags-on-post-deletion#comment-249274), [13](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101862/eeek-the-super-mega-expando-search-box-is-annoying-part-2#comment-259508), so this is 14 (I hope I got the count right). P.S. ＠CodyGray too slow, or given up?

Comment: Actually since June there's supposed to be [an extra 24 hours before auto-awarding](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remaining/74037#74037).

Comment: [This is not an isolated incident.](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/why-was-my-bounty-removed)

Comment: @Popular Tim's bounty was awarded before the bug fix as well, so surely it's the same bug. There must be other cases accross the network, it looks like all bounties that weren't manually awarded before 6 days would have been affected.

Comment: @Giles I just set a bounty on your question ... let me know who you would like to award it to

Comment: @waffles Thanks. I'd set the bounty in the hope of a better answer to a particular part of the question, which didn't come in the 6 days the bounty ran. Community happened to pick the closest thing to an answer to that part of the question. So I'm ok with Community's auto-award, but add that other +50 to the same answer if you like.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This was my bad ... I failed dismally in date math.

I moved the bounty grace period into a site setting, but totally reversed the math for it.

```
and p.BountyCloses < DATEADD(HH, 25, GETUTCDATE())
```

Was really supposed to be

```
and p.BountyCloses < DATEADD(HH, -25, GETUTCDATE())
```

Comment: Is the 25 hours just in case daylight saving time ends? (Or *starts*; that's also difficult date math for me.) Or is the grace period actually 25 hours?