# Bounty Bug: Awarded by "Community" After Six Days

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, community

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bounty auto-awarded after 6 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104919/bounty-auto-awarded-after-6-days)

I recently placed a `+50` Rep Bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179177/how-to-use-javascript-on-a-wpf-webbrowser-control-via-mvvm). On the sixth day, during active comment discussion and testing of a given solution, the bounty suddenly closed itself. The answer under discussion was awarded only +25 points, says it was closed by "Community" (not me). The answer turned out to work (though I later found a better one, after the bounty period). I wanted to award the full bounty to a working solution, but someone appears to have done it for me. A mod said he could not fix it, and to raise a question here.

1. What happened? Did some special ruleset close it early for half-credit?
2. Can TheCodeKing be properly awarded the full bounty, or is it too late?

Comment: The bounty award occurred on Sep 1 at 18:05. [The bug was fixed a bit later, on Sep 3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104919/bounty-auto-awarded-after-6-days/104941#104941). Still, someone should fix this for your case.

Comment: Well a mod told me this was beyond his ability. Who is able to fix this?

Comment: @Tim A community manager is looking into it

Comment: Since this is a duplicate, it should probably be deleted after the bug is fixed.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek, any chance we can wait to close this until after the bounty has been fixed?

Comment: @Tim Well, I'm not sure it actually can be fixed. I brought it up again; apparently they're waiting on a response from a developer

Comment: @MichaelMrozek oh... that's unfortunate.

Comment: I just started a bounty there ... let me know who you want me to pick

Comment: Codekings answer

Comment: @waffles, forgot to reply to you: Please select CodeKings Answer.