# Bounty expired before the expiry time?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, bounties

I had posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058381/how-to-call-oracle-function-with-return-value-using-linq-to-entities/6451669#6451669) and offered bounty of +50 on it. I guess it was around 7 hours left for the bounty to expire, and I received an answer. This was the only answer for the question, and the answer was also correct. But now after getting an answer, the question says "start a bounty". It doesn't show my offered bounty. Where has the bounty lost? How did it expire before the expiry time? I even accepted the answer as correct and upvoted the answer. But I am unable to offer the bounty to the person who answered the question.

Comment: Did you looked at : [faq#bounty] and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work ? When did the bounty disappeared? After the answer had been posted?

Comment: Yes @M'vy. As soon as the answer was posted, the bounty disappeared. Although I got a reminder email that the bounty will expire in 23 hours. This email was received at 08:54 PM yesterday. So it should expire at around 08:00 PM today. Right now it is 03:50 PM, but the bounty is expired. Strange !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was my bug, which has been fixed. I've also refunded your bounty.

If you want to start the bounty again, I'll make sure that [Syeda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058381/how-to-call-oracle-function-with-return-value-using-linq-to-entities/6451669#6451669) gets the award.

Comment: @Hasan - doh, we had just deployed some code that would allow developers to award bounties (a configuration option, off by default), but you beat me to it!

Answer (score 8):

This indeed strange, bounty got expired exactly 7 hours before it should.

[image]

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6058381/revisions

And the answer is posted few minutes after bounty is expired.

Comment: Weird! A time zone misconfiguration perhaps?

Comment: @Pekka, could be, I can't think of anything other than that.

Comment: Even I think that the issue would be due to what @Pekka said.

Comment: @Pekka: [Maybe this is related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remaining)? Introduction of new features often introduces new bugs.

Comment: @Hendrik oh, that was implemented? Great! Yeah, it might indeed have to do with that.