# Get the bounty back offered to someone by mistake

Tags: discussion, support, bounties

Am quite confused here. I just had a question [dismissing Progress Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250049/progress-dialog-dismissing-problem)   for which I had to set an bounty of 50 reps. The thing is that, I believe I have accepted a wrong answer first and have offered my bounty to a a non relevant answer. Though I am capable of changing my accepted answer, I am not allowed to re offer the bounty to correct answer. I know this is late, but this might help someone in the future. Can anyone clarify this.

Comment: I'm fine with the current design - giving bounty is permanent and non reversible action and that's how it should be. One just have to think twice before clicking answer in random and confirming the JS dialog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once the bounty is awarded, it's permanently awarded:

> Awarding a bounty cannot be undone.

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty

Incidentally, neither of those pages say it, but you have *24 hours* after the expiration of the bounty to make your award: [A grace period of one day to award the bounty after expiration (without remaining featured, of course)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remaining/74037#74037)

Answer (score 6):

Per this

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6250049/revisions

You manually awarded the bounty to a specific answer. This can only be done through a javascript confirm dialog so it is not possible to do accidentally.

Note that **accepting** an answer is a different and unrelated action. You can read about the background here.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

(there is one edge condition: if someone accepts an answer during the bounty period but fails to award the bounty, we assume they wanted the accepted answer to have the bounty; this would occur 24 hours after the bounty period is over.)

Comment: We should force users to confirm the confirmation dialogue.  Just to be sure.

Comment: *"You just clicked 'Yes'.  Aren't you sure that you didn't not want to award this bounty?"*