# The global FAQ should include information about the 24-hour wait period on starting a new bounty

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, faq-update-request

We had a [question on Programmers Meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/start-a-bounty-link-is-missing-for-my-question) about a user not seeing the "start a bounty" link on their post. It turned out that there was a bounty on it earlier and the [24-hour grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remaining/74037#74037) on awarding the bounty hasn't expired yet.

The user did check the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) and found that the relevant section doesn't mention the wait period.

Since that part of the FAQ is the same for all Stack Exchange sites, I'm posting this here as a feature request. The FAQ should be updated to include this information:

> There are a few other rules around bounties:
>
> - [...]
> - Once a bounty expires, a new bounty cannot be started for 24 hours after the bounty period ended to allow for automatic bounty calculations on the original bounty.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary; the question itself should have the info in that 24 hour period in the banner slot at the bottom.

Comment: @Jeff The banner just says that the question had a bounty. It reads more like a statement of fact and doesn't make it clear that a new bounty cannot be started for another X hours. There's a link to the bounty section in the FAQ on that banner, though, so I think amending the FAQ would help.

Comment: we can improve the existing text; anything else feels like a micro-optimization for one confused user.

Comment: @Jeff I'm not sure if it's easier to tweak the FAQ or the banner, but I think either would work. Thanks.

Comment: I prefer to adjust the "just in time" / "all up in your grill" text rather than assuming people will click through to another document and read it.

Comment: Man, I knew Jeff was from Cali, but I wasn't expecting to see him say "all up in your grill" any time soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We changed the copy at the bottom of the bountied question to read, **during the 24 hour grace period after the bounty ends**, as follows:

For users who do not own the question:

> This question had a bounty worth [+50] reputation from Foo that ended 22 hours ago; the grace period ends in 2 hours.

For the owner of the question:

> This question had a bounty worth [+50] reputation from Foo that ended 22 hours ago; you have 2 hours to award the bounty.