# Bounty not removed after time expired and no answers

Tags: support, bounties

I placed a bounty on a question of mine, and got no answers.  Instead of the bounty going away when it expired, it's still hanging out there.  I don't need the rep back, I just want to create another bounty and can't.

[image: Bad Bounty]

Comment: I imagine it will dissapear in 24 hours.  I'll find out in the morning.

Comment: @Jeff, I think the edge case of someone with no answers, not being able to do anything about his bounty out there is a bug.  How about a way of dismissing it (losing the bounty rep, with a warning dialog perhaps).

Comment: What's sad is that because we don't have a queueing system or allowed multiple bounties I've already forgotten which post I wanted to place a new bounty on.  I really envy those with good memories.

Comment: you could simply favorite it in the future, then view your favorites list in order of last favoriting

Comment: @Jeff, probably a good idea, I try not to keep adding to favorites since it's getting to big and still isn't searchable, but for these one-off situations I should do that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As of June 2011, bounty offerers may award bounties up to 24 hours after the bounty period ends, to allow them to evaluate answers posted at the end of the bounty period.

Answer (score 6):

Since the 23rd June 2011 all bounties have a 24 hour grace period after the usual 7 days, in which the person offering the bounty can award it. At the end of this 24 hour grace period the bounty will be automatically awarded or discarded following the previous rules.

See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remaining/74037#74037) answer by Jeff Atwood, specifically the edit:

> due to a lot of <s>whining</s> valued community feedback on this issue, I decided it can't hurt to extend the auto-award period 24 hours past the true end of the bounty. So, the question will stop being a bounty question at the *original scheduled time* but the auto-accept calculations will always occur *24 hours after that*.

The [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) post is also helpful, specifically relevant here is the point *What happens if there's no answer after the bounty period?*

---

All that said, I don't know if it preventing you from placing another bounty within the 24hr grace period is intentional or a bug.