# Why when the bounty is over do I not see how long I have to select an answer?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, bounties, expired-bounty

For example on meta I have a bounty that expires in 2 hours:
[image: 2 hours]

Ok so fine. I have 2 more hours until the bounty on this question expires and noone else can post an answer that is eligible.

On stack I have a question on which the bounty **expired** and I have yet to select an answer and that looks like this:

[image: 24 hours? From when?]

**24 Hours**? From when? **Yesterday**. Wow that is very descriptive...

Can we please make it so that the time for selecting an answer after a bounty has expired is just as dynamic as before it expired?

---

### Update:

This is what it says when I hover over the word `yesterday`:

> started at 2011-11-30 15:10:45Z
> ended at 2011-12-07 15:10:45Z

Comment: Did you try hovering over "yesterday"?

Comment: Are you sure the message won't update in an hour to say "23 hours"? I *think* it does, but I won't swear to it on the spot.

Comment: Anna's right. You did actually have 24 hours from the moment you took the screenshot, rounded to the nearest hour.

Comment: @AnnaLear it has said `24 Hours` since yesterday. I am updating my question with the hover over the word `yesterday`

Comment: @PopularDemand see my above comment. and I had just taken that screenshot before posting

Comment: @Pekka yes. see update. But that doesnt change the fact that the bold words should be updated in the same way.

Comment: Whoops, I thought _today_ was the 7th. I guess I once saw a bounty with a small amount of time left (like in your first screenshot) and misremembered it.

Comment: @PopularDemand lol **nope** :-P

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uItMv.png) *"This question had a bounty worth +50 reputation from Neal that ended yesterday; grace period ends in 24 hours"* [used to read](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remainin/74037#74037) something like *"This question had a bounty worth +50 reputation from ... that ended xx hours ago."* Still seems to me that the system thinks there's actually 24 hours left. (Though I know that does not match the time stamps you're seeing.)

Comment: Hmm, maybe my memory of dynamic/changing numbers during the grace period wasn't crazy after all. Perhaps when they changed the message format, they introduced a bug in the time math? Good find, @Arjan.

Comment: @Arjan lol I have no idea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oops, nice find, thanks.

This was the classic bug of `DateTime.Hours` ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.hours(v=VS.90).aspx)) versus `DateTime.TotalHours` ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours(v=VS.90).aspx)).

Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Haha. Thank you. Odd. It now says I have `23 Hours` to award the bounty. Why is that?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: Because the scheduled job that closes expired bounties hasn't run yet. You should hurry up if you want to award it.

Comment: Don't I have 24 hours since it expired. Do you know how long I have left?

Comment: You don't have *any* time left. As soon as the scheduled job runs (it happens hourly), the bounty is gone. So, anywhere between zero and fifty minutes.

Comment: Wow. ok ^_^ I am fine with losing the bounty. I need to set up a new one, I did not get anything good.