# Got only half of bounty, even after accepting?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, accepted-answer

My answer though got accepted has got only half of the initially offered bounty

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23484436/981616

The asker didnt accept the answer before the bounty ended so I got only half of the bounty. But it was told that I would get the other half after the user has accepted the bounty but in this case Its just half of the bounty.. Can anyone tell why?

**related links:**

[A grace period of one day to award the bounty after expiration (without remaining featured, of course)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remainin)

[How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

saw this section: *What happens if I feel my question is still unanswered?

What is automatic awarding?*

Comment: The bounty was awarded by Community on May 8, but the answer was accepted by the OP on May 9. There will not be any further change on the bounty amount once it has been awarded.

Comment: @Antony yes but the bounty was for 50 not 25... So was wondering.. :)