# Automatic bounty awarding - votes count up to which point considered?

Tags: discussion, bounties, expired-bounty

In the accepted answer to the question [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) it says,

If the author offered the bounty, and accepted an answer that was posted during the bounty period, that answer is awarded the full bounty.

> Otherwise, all or half of the bounty is awarded to the highest-scored
>   answer out of those which...
>
> - were posted after the bounty was started, and
> - have a score of at
>     least +2, and
> - were not written by the bounty starter.

Here the score of at least +2 votes means the number of votes it had at the moment bounty period is ended or at the moment calculation for automatic award is done? Lets say an answer had a score of 2 when the bounty period is ended and later it gets a downvote and score become 1. but its still the highest scoring answer. Will it get the bounty by automatic bounty award mechanism?

Comment: At the end of the 24h grace period after the bounty ends.

Comment: @Ano can't you see I have linked the question that you have mentioned as possible duplicate and quoted one of its answers as well in my question

Comment: Ano has now updated the FAQ, so it's answered there. It's better to have all (frequently asked) questions and answers about bounties in one place; it's not a shame having your question marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @developer That post has since been edited. Here on Meta, it's common to close questions as duplicates of FAQs, even if the information was later edited.

Comment: I didn't know about that. And that sounds a bit odd. Better to start a discussion on that as well ;)

Comment: Duplicate? Unfair! The related text in FAQ was added **after** this one is asked. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @iDebug I notice the same. But Glorifindel and Ano say in revious comments that it's usual in meta

Comment: @iDebug Once relevant info is added to the FAQ, it's an accepted practice to close it as a duplicate. It's not a negative mark against the question. Besides, the answer was there the whole time; I just made it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the term I use for this is *strategic downvoting*.

As per the post on the *[grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remainin/74037#74037)* that describes it unambiguously,

> edit: due to a lot of <strike>whining</strike> valued community
>   feedback on this issue, I decided it can't hurt to extend the
>   auto-award period 24 hours past the true end of the bounty. So, the
>   question will stop being a bounty question at the original scheduled
>   time but the auto-accept calculations will always occur 24 hours after
>   that.

It is at the end of the grace period. You don't have the 'advertising' benefits, but otherwise it counts as an active bounty. The automatic award *only* gets calculated at the end of it.

So, an answer that got +2 upvotes during the main bounty period will be *ineligible* for an auto-bounty award should it get downvoted to a +1 during the grace period.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It clears my problem. But why letting this strategic down-voting happen? wouldn't Calculating the autoaward before solve this? have it claculated beforehand and award it later after the grace period?

Comment: Its a bit of an edge case, I suppose but in *this* scenario, it simply means that the bounty period is *8* days. Its simpler if, for example, the bounty is awarded between that period. Anyway, most folks *wouldn't* do that unless the answer was not very good, or they felt the answer didn't quite fit the bounty reasons.

Comment: yeah, true enough. I wish i could upvote your answers and comments :)