# What can't I see the bounty on the answer?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, bounties

I awarded a bounty for my question about keys in vim on Feb 13th, to reward an existing answer. I delayed the final "OK" to get more views. Help said

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted).

I got an email on Feb 17th, reminding me I had a grace period. Bit early?

Better be sure: I `accepted` the answer straight away, when I noticed it had `2` votes. I did not see a button to "award the bounty", as I'm javascipt-disabled, but the answer was `accepted`.

Now, after the full 7 days has expired, I do not see the bounty on the relevant answer page and would like to ask: why not?

1. Question: [How do I make the h key go to prev tab if at start of file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/22775/182)
2. Answer: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22788/182
3. Bounty: https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/182/jalanb?tab=bounties&sort=offered
4. Help: https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/bounty
5. Meta Bounties: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)
6. Grace: [A grace period of one day to award the bounty after expiration (without remaining featured, of course)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remainin/74037#74037)

Comment: As you can see [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/posts/22775/revisions) you have not awarded the bounty to anyone.

Comment: If you want to use the advanced features of Stack Exchange, I'm afraid you'll have to enable JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

The bounty was not awarded because you did not manually award it and there was no qualifying answer to award it to automatically. A bounty can only go automatically to an answer that was posted *after* the bounty was started. From the bounty help page:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer **created after the bounty started** with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. **If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.**
>
> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an **answer posted during the bounty period**, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.

As both answers were posted before you started the bounty there was no qualifying answer to award it to manually.

Comment: OP claims to have accepted it after the bounty started.

Comment: @ChrisW The answer has to have been posted after the bounty.