# Bounties with no deadline

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties

Today I discovered that a number of Stack Exchange sites maintain a list of bounties with no deadline.  As this is unsupported by Stack Exchange, this is done outside the normal bounty system in an unofficial manner.  Each of these sites maintains a thread in the site's Meta titled "List of bounties with no deadline" or "List of bounties with no deadlines".

A [Google web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=intitle:%22List+of+bounties+with+no%22+site:stackexchange.com) returns the following such threads:

- [Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5243/58776)
- [French Language](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/785)
- [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/629)
- [Literature](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1091/15922)
- [Puzzling](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4399)
- [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12517/99942)

The Literature page does a decent job summarizing the intent and usage:

> One of the problems on Stack Exchange sites is that questions don't always receive good answers. While [unanswered questions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) are easy to find, this is not the case with **questions that have one or more answers that don't meet the criteria of the question asker** (or of other users on the site).
>
> For this reason, I am drawing some inspiration from other sites, such as [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5243) and [Puzzling](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4399):
>
> **This is a list of unofficial, deadline-less (hence not searchable) bounties offered by users on various challenges on the main site.**
>
> The list need not be limited to questions that already have an answer. You can offer bounties both for your own questions and for other people's questions.
>
> **Disclaimer**: There is no guarantee that the user will award the bounty for you in case you fulfil its requirement. Especially if the user isn't an active member anymore. The only guarantee is his/her written word.
>
> ---
>
> **Guidelines for updating**
>
> - To add a bounty, create an answer that contains a link to the question that needs a (better) answer and the bounty you are willing to award.
> - Answers can be commented on, allowing someone to notify the bounty's creator that the bounty may have been earned.
> - If a bounty has been awarded, delete the entry or move it to another section of the answer, with a title such as "Awarded".

Given that six different sites have adopted this approach, there is a demonstrated desire for this feature in certain Stack Exchange sites.  That being said, I'm sure there are good reasons for the current bounty system that I suspect would make this a less ideal fit for other sites.

Should official built-in support for bounties with no deadline, or a similar feature that meets the same needs, be added to the Stack Exchange network?  These should be viewable/searchable in some manner.  Possibly this should be opt-in by the site, if this would be beneficial to some types of sites but harmful to others.

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog It might, though I'm not familiar enough with how this feature is used in practice on each of those six sites to say definitively.

Comment: Very old answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74037/282094 - It's OK to re-ask.